# cron job -query data base to send emails

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a database with a list of email addresses and reminders, my php file

1 - checks for any dates that are 'today'

2 - uses phpmailer to send a reminder email

I need to setup a cron job to run the php file once a day (say 10am gmt) and run the .php file.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
0 10 * * * cd /var/www/htdocs && php myfile.php
```

take a look [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use command "crontab -e" to edit the crontab and add the following entry:

```
0 10 * * * /script/path/file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your crontab and set it up to run your php script. For 10am every day;

```
crontab -e
00 10 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/phpscripts/yourscript.php
```

Your php script should then access the DB, run a SELECT query on all users due to receive a mail on that date, and then use [phpmail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in a while (mysqli_fetch_assoc) loop to send out your pre-defined mail.

Hope this helps.

- Eoghan

Answer (score 0):

nano /etc/crontab

```
change user to user of webserver
              |
              |      Command you want to run
              |      |
              |      |
              v      V
0 10 * * * www-data php -f /var/www/website/scripts/email.php
```